# Do you need docker when coding locally with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I've just recently started working with vagrant/ansible then docker for deployment. I'm not really well oriented with docker yet and I've been reading a couple of tutorials with it. One thing that bugs me is that when I am developing locally, the changes don't reflect though this makes sense since it's running an image.

My question is, is there a way where I can have my changes reflect immediately via browser refresh like the traditional rails development w/o docker. I can see this being a pain to constantly build and run the latest image locally when I am still coding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can mount your working directory when starting container: `docker run -it --rm -v <full path to sources>:<full path within the container> <image>`. Might cause performance issue when using boot2docker on mac though. See https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume for details.